# Is there a way to solve the problem of printing multiple Rdlc reports when using the AspNetCore.Reporting library?

Tags: c#, rdlc, reportviewer

I am new to C#, I am working on an asp.netcore 3.1 project. I use the AspNetCore.Reporting library to generate reports, it works for one, but for several it doesn't. I searched the forums and saw it was a cache problem but I don't know how to fix it. Can someone help me please.

```
  string path = "";
        string mimtype = "";
        int extension = 1;
        Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        if (rpt== 1)
        {
            path = $"{this._env.WebRootPath}\\Reports\\Report1.rdlc";
            parameters = g.GetAll();
        }
        if (rpt== 2)
        {
            path = $"{this._env.WebRootPath}\\Reports\\Report2.rdlc";
            parameters = g.GetAll2();
        }
        if (rpt== 3)
        {
            path = $"{this._env.WebRootPath}\\Reports\\Report3.rdlc";
            parameters = g.etatFinAutres(_context.Balance.ToList());
        }

        LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport(path);
        var result = localReport.Execute(RenderType.Pdf, extension, parameters, mimtype);
        return File(result.MainStream, "application/pdf");
```

Comment: Consider Zipping all the reports as one file before sending the response.